# How to insert timestamp when using either of the Fill Color tool or the Paint Format tool

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have been using the code below to insert a timestamp in column `L` when a cell fill color in column `C` is changed to white.

The code is working well, but while it works when I choose the white color with the **Fill Color** paint bucket tool, it does not work when I use the **Paint Format** paint roller tool.

How do I make the code work with both of these tools?

[doubleunary's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159869/88163)

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j9CzSkvZDcHTDFfCb4LxZ-gT4PLAiKOifi3NsWZJu3U/edit#gid=0)

```
/**
* Inserts a timestamp when a cell is formatted by choosing a fill color.
* Runs on an installable 'on change' trigger.
* https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
*
* @param {Object} e The 'on change' event object.
*/
function insertTimestampOnFormatChange(e) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 28 October 2021
  const settings = {
    sheetsToWatch: /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i,
    colorsToWatch: /^(#ffffff)$/i,
    columnsToWatch: /^(3)$/i, // column C
    timestampColumn: 12, // column L
    timestampFormat: 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss',
  };
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  if (e.changeType !== 'FORMAT') {
    return;
  }
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (!sheet.getName().match(settings.sheetsToWatch)) {
    return;
  }
  const range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  if (!String(range.getColumn()).match(settings.columnsToWatch)) {
    return;
  }
  const now = new Date();
  const rowStart = range.getRow();
  const colors = range.offset(0, 0, range.getHeight(), 1).getBackgrounds().flat();
  colors.forEach((color, rowIndex) => {
    if (color.match(settings.colorsToWatch)) {
      sheet.getRange(rowStart + rowIndex, settings.timestampColumn)
        .setValue(now)
        .setNumberFormat(settings.timestampFormat);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try catching paint roller events with this [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers):

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 30 October 2021
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  if (e.value === undefined && e.oldValue === undefined) {
    e.changeType = 'FORMAT';
    insertTimestampOnFormatChange(e);
  }
}
```

The code detects whether the edit is possibly because of a paint roller event, and modifies the event object `e` before passing it to `insertTimestampOnFormatChange(e)`.

If you only ever use the paint roller tool, and never the **fill color** paint bucket tool, you can delete the `on change` trigger you have installed. To support both tools, you will have to keep both the simple trigger and the installable trigger.

Comment: I think  `e.value === undefined && e.oldValue === undefined` is a key element in your answer and, considering the OP's previous questions and comments, it might be worthy that you highlight it and to add the limitations (only works for using the Paint Paste on single cells)

Comment: The pattern will work with ranges of any size, not just ranges of a single cell.

Comment: Are you aware that `e.value` and `e.oldValue` are always `undefined` when `e.range` has more than one cell?

Comment: Yes. The purpose of the `e.value` test is to improve spreadsheet performance. The `insertTimestampOnFormatChange(e)` already includes the required additional tests.

Comment: Sorry for being late @doubleunary I have tried this function along with previous one but still when i use paint format it does not work. Doesn't paste Timestamp

Comment: The script in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j9CzSkvZDcHTDFfCb4LxZ-gT4PLAiKOifi3NsWZJu3U/edit#gid=0) is lacking the `onEdit(e)` function given above. Add it to make the paint format tool work.

Answer (score 1):

The following code lines

```
  if (e.changeType !== 'FORMAT') {
    return;
  }
```

make that the execution to stop when the value of the `changeType` is different than `FORMAT`. It's very likely that the value of `changeType` when using the paint format tool is equal to `OTHER`. You could confirm this by your self by including `console.log(JSON.stringify(e,null,' '))` before `return`. I.E.

```
  if (e.changeType !== 'FORMAT') {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e,null,' '));
    return;
  }
```

NOTE: Comment from the OP to [doubleunary's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159869/88163)

> This message appear in recent Execution view `Oct 29, 2021, 8:15:33 AM    Debug   {"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"EDIT","source":{},"triggerUid":"8886766","user":{"email": redacted ,"nickname": redacted}}` @doubleunary –
> ShRa
> [3 hours ago](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159868/insert-timestamp-when-cell-background-color-is-changed#comment146182_159869)

Be aware if that you remove the above `if` statement or if you change the `if` condition to not stop the script execution when `changeType` be equal to `'EDIT'`, the section of the code after it always / when any edit be made respectively, will be executed, not only when the cell color be changed.

One solution might be to keep the cell colors stored somewhere then an `'EDIT'` occurs, compare the corresponding stored cell color with the current color of the edited cell / range, then update the stored cell colors in preparation for future script executions. For this you might have a  copy of the sheet, use the Properties Service among other alternatives.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

Comment: Thank you for taking the interest in it and posted the answer. I have included your piece of script and it gives this message in execution https://imgur.com/BvYvhcy and https://imgur.com/R0Ly49W

Comment: Thanks. There was a typo (the second screenshot error message shows that). Answer fixed.

Comment: I am unable to get that one thing why `Format Paint` is unable to write Timestamp whereas scripts works for `Fill Color`

Comment: Do you already understand what is a JavaScript *object* and why this concept is relevant in Google Apps Script, what is a *Google Apps Script trigger*, and what is a *Google Apps Script trigger  event object*?

Comment: Yes i tried to understand the JS objects and triggers from Dev.Mozilla.org. But its really hard to get all the concepts in single day. and i want to ask that `On change` event does not support the `Paint Format` but supports to `fill Color.` is there any possibility to add as well `changeType` for `Edit`

Comment: Thanks for sharing that you are doing your best. You have to be patient as these topics are huge. From the events guide article linked in the answer: "changeType: The type of change (EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER)." In other words, both are supported but apparently they don't have the same `changeType` value, one uses `FORMAT` and the other uses `EDIT` (according to your comment to doubleunary's answer)

Comment: What i got from reading the articles and from the comments and posted answers. That `OnChange`  just works for `Fill Color` and does not support to `Format Paint` but `OnEdit` support this. If i use both Triggers then it will create cause in sheet and it would be impossible to track the Colors which has been changed to white default color. Because whenever data will be entered it will also record timestamp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130972/discussion-between-ruben-and-shra).